# Cygwin fatal error unable to configure ssh-host-config

Tags: bash, cygwin

I'm trying to install cygwin on windows XP SP2. After successfully installing, while opening Cygwin terminal it's showing the following error.

```
1 [main] -bash 4064 C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe: *** fatal error - prefork: couldn't create pipe process tracker, Win32 error 161
1 [main] -bash 3160 C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe: *** fatal error - prefork: couldn't create pipe process tracker, Win32 error 161
1 [main] -bash 3400 C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe: *** fatal error - prefork: couldn't create pipe process tracker, Win32 error 161
```

Comment: did you tried to open it with administrative privileges?

Comment: Errors of this type often result from a version incompatibility between the program you're running and the Cygwin DLL. Has the machine you're installing on had a previous Cygwin version installed on it? Was this an update from Cygwin 1.5 to Cygwin 1.7?

Answer (score 0):

As of Cygwin 1.7.19 (June 2013), Cygwin requires at least XP SP3, so you'll need to install the service pack first.